# PHP Parse error on filosofo-custom-image-sizes.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is this correct from this?

```
if( !is_array($size_name) ){
    $size_name = trim($size_name);
        }
```

Throu an error PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in filosofo-custom-image-sizes.php on line 24

To this?

```
if( !is_array($size_name) ){
    $size_name = implode('x', $size_name);
        }
```

Or the implode('x' part?
Or is an old function?

Comment: Your code does check if the variable $size_name in the array, but you didn't show where you have declared $size_name variable or that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an else condition  like the following.

```
  if( !is_array($size_name) ){
        $size_name = trim($size_name);
    }else{
        $size_name = $size_name[0] . 'x' . $size_name[1];
    }
```

Comment: firstly thank you... and there is an else but with return part only.

Comment: can you post more, like the whole function

Comment: There is a new version of this file :(, Im working with an outdated version.

Comment: `// Change the size format to be widthxheight
  if ( !is_array($size_name) ){
   //$size_name = trim($size_name);
   //$size_name = implode('x', $size_name);
   $size_name = explode('x', $size_name);
  }else{
   return;
  }code`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is because the if statement is reached too early when the PHP parser is parsing your code.

This can mean that you may have missed some sort of bracket ) or }, an apostrophe ' or any multitude of closing characters.

As for your first code snippet, [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), as specified in the PHP manual, simply removes whitespace at the beginning and end of your string. So all you are doing is checking if $size_name is an array and if it is not, you are removing the whitespace from it (Hopefully $size_name is a string).

In your second code snippet, you are trying to combine every index in the array $size_name with the string 'x'. So for example, if

> $size_name = array(1,2,3)

you would now have

> $size_name = '1x2x3'

What you really want to do after your check is [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string $size_name into its parts so that you can store it as an array.

```
if (!is_array($size_name))
{
    $size_name = explode('x', $size_name);
}
```

Comment: There is a new version of this file :(, Im working with an outdated version. But this is working. Thank you.